# fread (data.table) locks files

Tags: r, data.table

I have used `fread` from `data.table` package and when I try to modify or delete the file (just open with notepad) windows says:

[image]

How can I unlock this binding?

edit:

trying in R gives the same

```
cat(file="C:/Users/MCarrie/Desktop/test/test2.txt")
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/MCarrie/Desktop/test/test2.txt': Permission denied
```

info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.8.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.1

> showConnections(all=T)
  description class      mode text   isopen   can read can write
0 "stdin"     "terminal" "r"  "text" "opened" "yes"    "no"     
1 "stdout"    "terminal" "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
2 "stderr"    "terminal" "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"
```

file being read: (missing quote put on purpose)

```
"AA",3,4,5,"w"
"ss,2,3,4,"s"
"ww",2,3,3,"s"
```

Comment: I don't see this problem. W7. Please add the contents of a) `sessionInfo()` and b) `showConnections()` (if any output from that second command).

Comment: @SimonO101: did you try this via RStudio, because it could be specific to that interface.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich exactly, via RStudio on W7. I declined to give version numbers etc because they are not in the OP so kinda useless until that info is shared. Also, I wonder if they opened another connection in the same session.

Comment: @SimonO101 also R itself can't see update

Comment: @nigmastar please add the requested info. Also, do you see this issue if you open R with administrator privilleges? (Right click R and Run as administrator).

Comment: @SimonO101 yes it does the same (it just says "is open in R for Windows GUI..." instead)

Comment: Why'd you truncate the output of `sessionInfo()`?  It was just about to get to the useful part.

Comment: @GSee done. Some ideas of what is going on?

Comment: The error I got looks much different than yours; it says `Unbalanced " observed on this line: "ss,2,3,4,"s"`

Comment: Pardon the dumb question, but does `data.table::fread` execute a `close` when it's completed the read?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yes, but it wasn't executed because of the error. @MatthewDowle, should there be a close `on.exit()`?

Comment: @GSee Ahah - I get it now. Will take a look ...  (Btw, S.O. only allows one <at> in each comment I believe. I didn't get notified of the <at>MatthewDowle because it was 2nd, I think).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Ahah - thanks for seeing through the mud - that might be it!  Will take a look ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please retry with data.table v1.8.11. There's a new .zip for Windows on the [data.table homepage](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/).

From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) :

> If fread returns a data error (such as unbalanced quotes on a particular line) it now closes the file first rather than holding a lock open, a Windows only problem. Thanks to nigmastar for reporting and Carl Witthoft for the hint. Tests added.

Comment: uau! Nice, I checked just this morning for 1.8.9 and was still in dev today. Thanks!! (I hope to see add/modify/delete rows by reference in 1.8.11 soon :-)... ) 

Anyway, have you noticed the missing double quote in the text file used above? The issue happens only in this case.

Comment: @Michele I noticed the double quote but it's not that, surely, is it? It's a file open/lock issue when nigmastar has tried to edit the file to fix that missing quote. On Windows. Hopefully v1.8.10 fixes it.

Comment: @nigmastar See new answer. Please confirm if that fixes it. Thanks.

Comment: @MattDowle Hi Matt, I'm using v1.10.4 and have file lock issue on windows. This line had an extra separator somewhere (\t).
Expecting 5 cols, but line 18087 contains text after processing all cols.

Comment: @bezout Lot's of recent work on `fread` and much better on Windows. Please try [Windows binary .zip from dev](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation#windows)  (no compile tools needed).

Comment: @bezout It is bug fix 4 in dev mentioned on [News](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) page:  `fread() no longer holds an open lock on the file when a line outside the large sample has too many fields and generates an error, #2044. Thanks to Hugh Parsonage for reporting.`